# PO Box RegEx Issue

Tags: regex

@"(?i)\b(?:p(?:ost)?.?\s*o0?.?\s*b(?:[o0]x)?|b[o0]x)"

I have the above RegEx to catch PO Box, however it is not catching one scenario that I would like:

PO 123 (or any given set of Numbers after PO)
PO 756
PO 987 - etc.

Can I get some assistance on where the matching issue is? It seems like it is only matching 'PO' if it contains  'B' or 'BOX' after it.

I have looked at the numerous other examples on this site - and none seem to catch this particular scenario.

Comment: If your data is cleanly separated (eg into normal address fields), you can look for `^p\.o` in a stripped copy of the string and split on space to get the number at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about making the b optional?, just add a `?` after the `b` like this

```
(?i)\b(?:p(?:ost)?.?\s*o0?.?\s*b?(?:[o0]x)?|b[o0]x)
```